# Out of memory error for mongoimport command

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

When I am using **mongoimport** to import **19.4GB** data to mongodb:

mongoimport --db hui --collection gnd --file rdf_json.old --host localhost:#####

I got this **error**:

> runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 106037248-byte block (137354018816 in use)
>   fatal error: out of memory

My system is **64** bit. Does anybody know what's wrong with this import?

Comment: Sounds like the whole "import" is specified as a single array, rather than line based. Which basically means the "utility" is trying to load the whole content into memory before doing anything. So whatever you are doing to "write the file", then don't use a JSON array notation wraping the whole content.

Comment: Thx for your tip. I use raptor to convert rdf file to json format. Do you know any other command line tool to convert rdf file to line based json format?

Comment: Well if the basic problem is that the exported result is basically an "array" and not "line based", then the simple solution is to remove the brackets from the file `[]` data and then replace each trailing "comma" after an object with a newline character instead. Plenty of common tools to do that.

Comment: Thx, I will try it tmr.